# Value not accessible outside valuechangelistener of Inputfile during fileupload in Oracle ADF

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, oracle-adf, valuechangelistener

I am creating a form in Oracle ADF in which i am using inputfile to upload a file to db. When i select a file through input file value is recieved in the ValueChangeListener but if i try to access that value outside the valuchangelistener function through public variables or getter , setter functions the value recieved is null.

```
// Value Change Listener for inputFileComponent
    public void onFileUploadVCL(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
        file=(UploadedFile)valueChangeEvent.getNewValue();
        // get the file name
        uploadedFileName=file.getFilename();
        // get the mime type
        contentType = file.getContentType();
        // get blob
        blob=getBlob(file);      
    }

  //submit function where i need to use values

   public void onSubmit(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        // Add event code here...
        System.out.println("String:"+inEmpCode+"#"+outDesignation+"#"+inFromDate+"#"+inToDate+"#"+uploadedFileName+"$$"+blob);
        insertRow(inEmpCode,inFromDate,inToDate,uploadedFileName,blob);               
    }
```

// Code from its view

```
                            <af:selectOneChoice value="#{AddReviewBean.inEmpCode}"
                                                label="#{bindings.Empcode.label}"
                                                required="#{bindings.Empcode.hints.mandatory}"
                                                shortDesc="#{bindings.Empcode.hints.tooltip}" id="soc1"
                                                valueChangeListener="#{AddReviewBean.onSelectionChange}" autoSubmit="true">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{bindings.Empcode.items}" id="si1"/>
                                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.Empcode.validator}"/>
                            </af:selectOneChoice>

                            <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <af:inputText value="#{AddReviewBean.outDesignation}" readOnly="true" label="Designation" id="txtDesignation"
                              partialTriggers="soc1"/>
            </p>
             <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <af:inputDate label="From" id="dateTxtFrom" required="true" value="#{AddReviewBean.inFromDate}"/>
            </p>
            <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <af:inputDate label="To" id="dateTxtTo" required="true" value="#{AddReviewBean.inToDate}"/>
            </p>

            <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <af:inputFile label="Upload Review" maximumFiles="1" autoSubmit="true" id="inFileReview"
                          valueChangeListener="#{AddReviewBean.onFileUploadVCL}" value="#{AddReviewBean.file}"/>
            </p>
            <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

                <af:button partialSubmit="true" text="Submit" id="btnSubmit"
                           actionListener="#{AddReviewBean.onSubmit}"/>
            </p>

        </af:panelFormLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add the form code to your question ?

Comment: @MrAdibou done !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your variables as static and it should work.

Comment: Thanks it worked !!.. I was declaring variables as public and it was getting null as soon as it gets out from ValueChangeListener.

Comment: This is definitely a bad idea, setting it to static means that the next user accessing this page will have that variable data of another user's uploaded file!!!

Answer (score 0):

The variable will remain there if you declared your managed bean inside pageFlowScope or sessionScope (if you think it should survive the whole user session) and make the variable private (not static).